# fabric.Canvas is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, canvas, constructor, fabricjs

I've included fabric like so: `<script src="js/fabric_freedrawing.js"></script>`

But when I use it like this:

```
var canvas;

function initSketchPad() {
    canvas = new fabric.Canvas('sketch-pad', {
        isDrawingMode: true
    });

}
```

I get

> Uncaught TypeError: fabric.Canvas is not a constructor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what you have in your `fabric_freedrawing.js` file but adding your code to a snippet below seems to work just fine.

```js
var canvas;
function initSketchPad() {
    canvas = new fabric.Canvas('sketch-pad', {
        isDrawingMode: true
    });
}

initSketchPad();
```

```css
canvas {
  border:1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.4/fabric.min.js"></script>
<canvas height=300 width=300 id="sketch-pad">
```

Comment: Apparently it works when including the entire Fabric library, instead of using the builder

Answer (score 0):

your version of fabric.js isnt up to date all just not working well all u gotta do is download a new one simple just download it from here

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.4/fabric.min.js